# automatic mail sending error

Tags: batch-file, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a service which sends mails to all the users of my application post midnight everyday.

When I'm running the batch file manually the mails go without any error or exception. But, when I schedule the task post mid night there is an exception like this-

```
sending failed::javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.nowcsm.com; nested exception is:java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.nowcsm.com
```

here is my batch file-

```
echo %PATH%
set CLASSPATH=D:\Tomcat\webapps\TESTSMPP\WEB-INF\classes;D:\SMPP\LIB\datedFileAppender-1.0.2.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\log4j-1.2.11.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\imap.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\activation.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\smtp.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\mailapi.jar;D:\smpp\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;D:\smpp\lib\commons-pool-1.3.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\jtds-1.2.jar;D:\SMPP\LIB\sqljdbc.jar;.;
echo %CLASSPATH%
java -Xms40m -Xmx128m com.credensys.general.QuotaAndDailyReport1 >> D:\SMPPServices\DailyEmailLogs\Systemout.log
pause;
```

Please help me out.

thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it looks like your batch file is fine, does this happen every night, or is it a one off? Maybe the SMTP server was down, the exception indicates it's the Java bit that's thrown it.

Comment: thanks. i guess the server was down that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it manually, do you run it on the same machine that the batch job runs on?

"Unknown host" usually means you gave it an incorrect host name, or the name service is not configured correctly and can't look up that host name.  Perhaps you're behind a firewall that prevents direct access to the internet?